# Create UITableView programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to implement UITableView programmatically without use of xib or Storyboards. This is my code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let table: UITableViewController = MyTableViewController()
        let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 500)
        tableView.dataSource = table
        tableView.delegate = table

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
}
```

**MyTableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        NSLog("sections")
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        NSLog("rows")
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        NSLog("get cell")
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = "foo"
        return cell
    }  
}
```

But when I run app, all I get is empty table. In log I see a few lines of `sections` and `rows`, but no `get cell`. How can I fix this code to get table with 6 lines of `foo` text?

Comment: Why do you have both a `ViewController` with its own table view and a `MyTableViewController` which also have its own table view?

Comment: `MyTableViewController` is getting released after the `viewDidLoad`. So try keeping a reference.

Comment: If you are new to iOS and Swift I strongly recommend you follow a tutorial on either the web or iTunesU. The Stanford course on iTunesU called `Developing iOS 9 Apps with Swift` will explain about object graphs and how to use the iOS frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for answers, New16's answer helped me.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Note:** As you mentioned you just started programming in `Swift`. I created a tableView programmatically. `Copy` and `paste` below code into your `viewController` and **run** the project...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let myArray: NSArray = ["First","Second","Third"]
    private var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let barHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
        let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height

        myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))
        myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
        print("Value: \(myArray[indexPath.row])")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: i am getting an error when i try to register a prototype cell. any solution or work around. im using swift 4

Comment: @ZahurafzalMirza Above code should work fine in Swift 4. Whats your error log says?

Comment: @Joe  didSelectRowAt Method is not invoking,

Comment: how customize the tableCell Element like adding Image ? and count of cell in each row ?

Comment: @Criss You have to create a customTableviewCell to add image and etc. Follow this tutorial may help https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Comment: Great example, only one thing:

UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height

is deprecated you can use instead:

view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0

Answer (score 24):

**Updated for Swift 3**

*Option 1:*

```
import UIKit
//
// MARK :- TableViewController
//
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let headerId = "headerId"
    private let footerId = "footerId"
    private let cellId = "cellId"

    //
    // MARK :- HEADER
    //
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 150
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerId) as! CustomTableViewHeader
        return header
    }

    //
    // MARK :- FOOTER
    //
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 150
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: footerId) as! CustomTableViewFooter
        return footer
    }

    //
    // MARK :- CELL
    //
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 150
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "TableView Demo"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupTableView()
    }

    func setupTableView() {

        tableView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerId)
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewFooter.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: footerId)
        tableView.register(CustomTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
}

//
// MARK :- HEADER
//
class CustomTableViewHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

//
// MARK :- FOOTER
//
class CustomTableViewFooter: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .green
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

//
// MARK :- CELL
//
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

*Option 2:* replace above *Option 1* TableViewController with this class

```
import UIKit
//
// MARK :- ViewController
//
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let headerId = "headerId"
    private let footerId = "footerId"
    private let cellId = "cellId"

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {

        let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.register(CustomTableViewHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: self.headerId)
        tv.register(CustomTableViewFooter.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: self.footerId)
        tv.register(CustomTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellId)
        return tv
    }()

    //
    // MARK :- HEADER
    //
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 150
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerId) as! CustomTableViewHeader
        return header
    }

    //
    // MARK :- FOOTER
    //
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 150
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: footerId) as! CustomTableViewFooter
        return footer
    }

    //
    // MARK :- CELL
    //
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 150
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "TableView Demo"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        setupAutoLayout()
    }

    func setupAutoLayout() {

        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you don't want header or footer, just removed the respective marks codes and comment the tableView.register line..

Comment: For option 2, in swift 4, adding the delegate and the dataSource inside the tableView declaration (e.g. tv.dataSource = self) throws an error. Instead, I had to define the dataSource and the delegate in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @GeorgeBikas kindly do with lazy var tableView instead of let tableView then it's working...

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4** compatible

Instead of adding a `UITableView` to your `UIViewController`, you should consider creating a `UITableViewController` and avoid setting up delegates:

```
class YourTVC: TableViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // setup custom cells if you use them
    tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourCell")
  }

  // MARK: tableView
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3 // set to value needed
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell at row \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense that you are using a `UITableViewController` as the data source and delegate for your view controller's table view. Your own view controller should be the table view's data source and delegate.

Since you seem to want a view controller with a table view that doesn't take up the entire view, move every thing to your view controller as follows:

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 500)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        NSLog("sections")
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        NSLog("rows")
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        NSLog("get cell")
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = "foo"
        return cell
    }  
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to create a struct ( or the data model ) away from the VC ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to make a separate class for UITableView. Just in your ViewController class implement protocols of UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource and then implement delegate methods.
I think your code should be like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let table: UITableViewController = MyTableViewController()
        let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 500)
        tableView.dataSource = table
        tableView.delegate = table

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        NSLog("sections")
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        NSLog("rows")
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        NSLog("get cell")
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = "foo"
        return cell
    } 
}
```

Tell us more info or show logs if you still face issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in that the data would not populate for my programmatic UITableView. This was because I was using a delegate/dataSource without a strong reference. Once I kept a reference to it (I had one class implementing both UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate), the data was populated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(TableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = "TableViewCell programtically"
    cell.nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
    cell.nameLabel.textColor  = .white
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```